# Custom query to filter posts that have current post as a taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, filters, taxonomy, query

**Introduction**

I'm a graphic designer that knows nothing about PHP, but I need to get my hands dirty in this particular situation and I need help from the coding gods. I've been struggling with this problem quite a bit, reading about it and trying stuff, but I'm probably too noob to figure it out.

**Toolkit**

I have a Wordpress site and I'm using Elementor Pro to build it. I'm using the plugins "CPT-UI" to have my own custom post types, and "CPT-onomies" to be able to use a CPT as a taxonomy for another CPT. From Elementor I can call a custom query if I'm able to write it within the "Snippets" plugin.

**The circumstances**

That said, I'll describe exactly what's going on: I have a "Projects" CPT and a "Designs" CPT, both are CPTs. At the same time, "Projects" is a taxonomy related to "Designs", this means that I can group many designs that belongs to the same big "Project". For example, if I've designed Coca-Cola's logo and also designed business cards with that logo, then both designs would be grouped into the taxonomy (which is also a CPT) called "New Coca Identity". So from within the "New Coca Identity" page (which is actually a dynamic template applied to all "Projects") I can fetch all designs which have the current loop id ("New Coca Identity" in this case) assigned as their taxonomy.

**Should be something like this (I believe)**

So this is what I came up with...

```
// Create the action to call this query from Elementor
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query/projects_designs_query', function($query)
{

// Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

// If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

// Append our meta query
    $tax_query[] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'projects',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => 'HERE SHOULD BE THE DYNAMIC ID I GUESS',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with how elementor does things but what you have makes sense... ...the only question is 'where are you getting the 'term' from'?
If it's a template that gets reused, then you'll want to obtain the term from somewhere? But your `tax_query` is looking for the ID of the term. So we have to get the slug from the cpt object, then find the term that has the matching slug, then use that to get the ID of that term, then loop back and get all the entries with that term ID?

Comment: Hi @TonyDjukic , thank you for your help. As far as I've been reading, to get the "post id" of the current post, which should match the "term id" that we want, we need something like this... `$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );` I've read that 'p' returns the post's ID, but I'm writting this code based only on similar examples.

Comment: Don't take my word as a sure thing since I don't know any PHP syntax and I'm just building a frankenstein, copying and modifying codes that seem to be similar to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I made it through! I'll share how I did in case some other person lacking the php knowledge like me lands in the same spot.

```
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query/projects_designs_query', function($query)
{

$post_id = get_the_ID();

$meta_query[] = [
            'post_type' => 'designs',
            'taxonomy' => 'projects',
            'value' => $post_id,
            'compare' => 'in',
];
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

What this achieves is firstly getting the ID of the current post in the loop (which in my case is a Project custom post type). Then it gets all the post (with custom post type Design) that belong to the same project (the current post).